# Custom Layercontrol Overlay Leaflet / React Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, javascript, react

I am new to React Leaflet and have some experience with Leaflet. Now I am trying to build a custom Overlay to manage the markers in my map, and came accross this example which seems to be perfect for my needs : https://reactjsexample.com/custom-layers-control-for-react-leaflet-with-typescript/

Can I use React Leaflet code in Leaflet and which adjustments need to be done to use the code?

I also found some code from this example which I will include here: https://codesandbox.io/s/13hld

So far I tried editing the css files a bit without any real success.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, Please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Please [Edit] the Question to focus on one task.